Kafka Producer - JSON Schema Refistry - Unknown Schema Registry Error: b""
I want to use confluent_kafka.Producer (python client) to generate messages in JSON format and produce them to the Kafka topic, and, first of all, I want to test it locally:
the Kafka-stack is running on my local machine using the "kafka-monitpring-stack-docker-compose" pack.
For data serialisation I use confluent_kafka.schema_registry.json_schema.JSONSerializer, and the following JSON schema (taken from the internet):
JSON_SCHEMA_STR = """
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "first_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "last_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's last name."
    },
    "age": {
      "description": "Age in years which must be equal to or greater than zero.",
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    }
  }
}
"""

For starting the Producer and producing messages I run the following code:
from confluent_kafka import Producer
from confluent_kafka.serialization import SerializationContext, MessageField
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.json_schema import JSONSerializer

schema_registry_client = SchemaRegistryClient(
    {
        'url': "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"
    }
)
json_serializer = JSONSerializer(JSON_SCHEMA_STR, schema_registry_client, to_dict=func)  # some `to_dict` function
my_producer = Producer({"bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"})
topic = "MY_TOPIC_TO_PRODUCE"
messages = [] # messages are here

for message in messages:
    my_producer.poll(0.0)
    my_producer.produce(
        topic=topic,
        value=json_serializer(
          message,
          SerializationContext(topic, MessageField.VALUE)
        ),
        on_delivery=ack  # some ack
  )

and I receive the following Exception:
File "/kafka/producer.py", line 15, in produce
  value=json_serializer(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/json_schema.py", line 256, in __call__
  self._schema_id = self._registry.register_schema(subject,
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/schema_registry_client.py", line 337, in register_schema
  response = self._rest_client.post(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/schema_registry_client.py", line 128, in post
  return self.send_request(url, method='POST', body=body)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/schema_registry_client.py", line 180, in send_request
  raise SchemaRegistryError(response.status_code,
confluent_kafka.schema_registry.error.SchemaRegistryError: Unknown Schema Registry Error: b'' (HTTP status code 405, SR code -1)

I assume that this problem may relate to the invalid url in SchemaRegistryClient but I really don't know what I should specify here and therefore need help

The url for the registry client needs to point to a valid registry server, not the json schema spec. HTTP status code 405 means you couldn't send a POST request for a schema to that url. Have you started a Schema Registry server, in addition to the Kafka broker?

@OneCricketeer thanks you for this advice! I ran Kafka schema registry in separate docker-container (port 8081) and specify the "schema_registry_url" as "localhost:8081", but now I receive the error: urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (I have openssl installed locally)

By default, there's no security enabled, so I'm not sure why you'd get ssl errors. Don't use https prefix on the address
